# MySQL ordering rows by

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

I'm trying to pull data from my `forum_topics` and `forum_replies` tables to get the last reply date;

```
SELECT 
    (SELECT date FROM forum_replies WHERE topic=5 AND date < NOW()
    ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1) as lastreply, 
    ft.* FROM forum_topics ft
    ORDER by lastreply DESC LIMIT 5
```

It's getting the `lastreply` data in the recordset, but not using it to ORDER the rows of the recordset.

I can see why, but not sure how to fix it?

Comment: As per your current query, it shall always return same value for lastreply. I think you mean to use Correlated subquery instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use correlated subquery:

```
SELECT 
    (SELECT r.date FROM forum_replies r WHERE ft.topic = r.topic
    ORDER BY r.id DESC LIMIT 1) as lastreply, 
    ft.* 
FROM forum_topics ft
ORDER by lastreply DESC LIMIT 5
```